# How to perform an action when UITableViewCell is in highlighted state?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uipopovercontroller

Is it possible to perform an action when a UITableViewCell is highlighted? For example I have a UITableViewCell with clickable labels and buttons. I want to display a popover when the cell is highlighted/touched anywhere, so that the popover is shown without any interference with the labels & buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the tableView's delegate method `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.